# laravel is saving the wrong image link in db

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5

I am trying to save the image link in the db like this

```
'photo' => asset('uploads/'.$fileName2)));
```

and in the db it is being saved as

```
http://localhost:8000/uploads/8730.jpeg
```

irrespective of the url in config file

```
APP_URL=http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asset()` helper function generates

> a URL for an asset using the current scheme of the request

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset

Then, When you access to your laravel app via `http://localhost:8000/`, `asset('uploads/'.$fileName2)` will returns `http://localhost:8000/uploads/...`.